# How to add/update Hyperledger-Fabric Orderer Address

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to remote organization joins to my Fabric network. But when I created Orderer, I just declare one value of Orderer Address, like this:

```
Addresses:  
  - orderer0.orderer:7050
```

It's internal address, so remote organization can't connect to fabric network. I tried to update orderer address, adding another external Orderer's DNS address, everything is ok but it affects to the last block, not genesis block. But when the remote organization join to the channel, it fetch block 0 (genesis block) and then synchronize data. Problem is my genesis block just have an internal address, not have external address, which I edit in the last block.
Could anyone have ideas about my case? Edit OrdererAddress and make remote organization to network.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... this is a known problem. Please read [FAB-5288](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5288)